# Gateway SX2300-01u CPU/PSU issues

Tags: cpu, power-supply, gateway

I have a 2-yr-old Gateway SX2300-01u with an AMD Phenom X3 8550 that I feel has about a year or so of life left, but I am having a couple of hardware issues that I have not been able to resolve.

First, the power supply fan sounds like much louder than before and the PSU itself is really hot. The PSU model (Liteon PS 5221-06) is not available at a reasonable price; are there any good alternatives? Could I replace just the PSU fan?

Also, the CPU fan failed sometime back, but my replacement, which supposedly fits the MB (Socket AM2+) doesn't actually fit properly. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

"are there any good alternatives? "

We don't typically answer shopping questions here but one name comes to mind is power-on.com

"Could I replace just the PSU fan?"

We don't know what your skill are, it can be done but we do not recommend it since there are hazards involved such as electric shock from the capacitors inside the PSU.

"Any idea why?"

How could we possibly know why with the little information you have supplied?